# JavaScript: getting 'NaN' from an input value

Tags: javascript, input, nan

First time trying JavaScript, and for now I just want to make sure the site recognises the value that I'm inputting by having the console print it back at me. For some reason, I keep getting NaN as the result, and I can't figure out why.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="question-1">
            <label class="fnum">Enter your first number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum">
        </form>

        <form class="question-2">
            <label class="snum">Enter your second number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="snum" name="snum">
        </form>
```

Javascript:

```
const buttonAdd = document.querySelector(".plus");

buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
   var num1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".fnum").value);
   var num2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".snum").value);
   console.log(num1);
   console.log(num2);
});
```

html includes: `<button class="plus">+</button>`

Comment: It is a javascript problem, not a java problem.

Comment: @TheKNVB sorry and thanks, I wasn't aware that was something else, I've changed the wording

Comment: This is caused by a typo.  Should be `#fnum` and `#snum`, not `.fnum` and `.snum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const buttonAdd = document.querySelector(".plus");

buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
   var num1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#fnum").value);
   var num2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#snum").value);
   console.log(num1);
   console.log(num2);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <form class="question-1">
            <label class="fnum">Enter your first number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum">
        </form>

        <form class="question-2">
            <label class="snum">Enter your second number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="snum" name="snum">
        </form>
        <button class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Your query selector is wrong.

```
document.querySelector(".fnum")
```

This is for what class name is fnum.

```
document.querySelector("#fnum")
```

Should be like the above for id.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `document.querySelector(".fnum")` just return the `<label class="fnum">Enter your first number:</label>` element, not the `<input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum">` element, so it does not have `.value` attribute,
therefore, `document.querySelector(".fnum").value` return null.

To get the value of `<input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum">`, you can use `document.getElementById("fnum").value` to do so.

For the `<input type="number" id="snum" name="snum">` element, the problem is the same.